# Ruby hashes, duck typing and JSON deserialization

Tags: ruby, json

I am pretty new to Ruby and currently discovering its differences from Java, consider the following code snippet:

```
file = File.new('test.json', 'w')
hash = {}
hash['1234'] = 'onetwothreefour_str'
hash[1234] = 'onetwothreefour_num'

puts hash.to_json
file.write(hash.to_json)
file.close

str = File.read('test.json')
puts str
puts JSON.parse(str)
```

it outputs

```
{"1234":"onetwothreefour_str","1234":"onetwothreefour_num"}
{"1234":"onetwothreefour_str","1234":"onetwothreefour_num"}
{"1234"=>"onetwothreefour_num"}
```

so, after deserialization we have one less object in hash. 
Now, the question - is it normal behaviour? I think that it is perfectly legal to store in hash keys of different types. If so, then shouldn't JSON.parse write to file keys as '1234' and 1234?

Just to be clear - I understand that it's better to have keys of the same type, I just saw that after restoring my object has them as strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ruby hashes can have keys of whatever type.

JSON spec, on the other hand, dictates that object keys must be strings, no other type allowed.

So that explains the output you observe: upon serializing, integer key is turned into a string, making it a duplicate of another key. When reading it back, duplicate keys are dropped (last one wins, IIRC). I'm pretty sure you would get the same behaviour if you tried to use that json from javascript.

Comment: here was a catch - I never thought that keys in JSON are typed by specs, though it raises another question - why to_json allows duplicate keys in output.

Comment: @Andrez: because json spec doesn't forbid this, obviously :)

Comment: Oh, hell. That's another piece of news :) Still, I'd make these methods consistent. And put it to specs too, because it doesn't make any sense. And I'd prefer to live in the world where serializing/deserializing doesn't change object :)